# Can I return to the UK after having made a short emergency visit?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens

My husband and I went to the UK on July 8, 2016. We got married in the UK on September 5, 2016. I was given a 6-month leave to enter because my husband is a UK citizen.

Unfortunately I had to return to the United States. So on January 6, 2017 I returned to the United States as my husband stayed in the UK. He fell very ill and I was immediately sent back to the UK on February 14, 2017 by his mother. When I landed the immigration wasn't pleased to see that I had left and came back immediately. I explained my situation and they granted me only 2 days to be with my husband, which will fully complete my 6-month visa. They held my passport and made a flight for me to return to NYC on February 16, 2017. I did as instructed, to avoid any problems.

It has now been a year and I am wondering if I can return to the UK or I have I been banned? Am I able to return with just a visitor's visa or will I need another kind of visa to be with my husband?

Comment: I don't see why they should have banned you.

Comment: What visa you need will depend on how long you're planning to stay in the UK. Is your husband still living there while you're in the US? If so be careful, a visitor visa might be rejected if you can't show a very good reason why you are living in a different country from your husband.

Comment: You say your husband stayed in the UK, then fell very ill and was immediately sent back to the UK?

Comment: You were probably given a six-month leave to enter the UK because that's the routine grant of leave to enter for US citizens.  People are given something other than six months only in exceptional circumstances.  The answer to your question about the documents you'll need to return depends on how long you want to stay in the UK. Can you edit that information into your question?  (Also, if you intend to remain the UK, you should be asking at [Expatriates.SE] rather than here at [Travel.SE].)

Answer (score 1):

> **Am I able to return with just a visitor's visa or will I need another kind of visa to be with my husband?**

If you are spending (or have attemped to spend) more than six-months in the UK, with only a few days out of the UK, it looks like you are effectively residing (or trying to reside) in the UK. Using a visitor-visa or otherwise gaining leave to enter as a visitor are probably inappropriate under those circumstances.

If you just want to visit the UK for a few weeks, and **can show you have good reasons to return to the US** (leaving your husband in the UK?) - you shouldn't have much problem.

The usual advice in this Q&A website seems to be to apply for a visitor visa if you have any doubts and wish to avoid any possibility of spending several hours being questioned and/or being refused entry.

If you want to spend the majority of the year (or several years) living in the UK, you should ask about appropriate visas etc on [Expatriates.stackexchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may return to the UK and you still need a valid visa to do so.

Your prior experiences can be summarized as "used a visitor visa to gain entrance and left within the expected time", so I don't see any reason to not allow you back into the country.

Comment: Why does the OP need a valid visa in order to visit?  I'm not saying it'd be a bad idea, but I'm not sure why you think they *need* it.